# JS: How to check if the JSON contains a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, validation

### Problem

Im working with an array containing multiple events (names & dates) for each event i have to create a point in a SVG.

For each new Date X = X + 5.
For each event on the same date Y = Y + 5.

ex:

event 1: date = 1970 X = 10 & Y = 10

event 2: date = 1970 X = 10 & Y = 15

If a point has been drawn i save the position in an JSON. How can i now validate if the position exists in the JSON?

#### What i tried

```
    var var events = [{TITLE:"event 1", DATE:"1970"},
                      {TITLE:"event 2", DATE:"1970"},
                      {TITLE:"event 3", DATE:"1970"}];
    var pos_reserved = [];
    var X = 10;
    var Y = 10;
    if (pos_reserved.X != X && pos_reserved.Y != Y){
      Y = 30;
    }
    else if (pos_reserved.X == X && pos_reserved.Y == Y)
    {
      Y = 10;
    }
    else {}
    pos_reserved.push({"X": X,"Y": Y});
    create_point(X, Y);
```

Comment: Do you have your example JSON? (please edit  your question)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. In this case update your question with complete example and show expected and actual output - for example what is `standard_X `

Comment: As a note: JSON is textual data interchange format that has to be parsed before it can be used. `pos_reserved` is an array and not an object, so `pos_reserved.X` looks wrong.

Comment: That code makes no sense. You are not using the JSON anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem fully but I'm gonna try to help you anyway...

In my opinion, one possibility would be to save the data in an object pos_reserved and do something like that

```js
var pos_reserved = {};

// returns if a position is already reserved or not
function isReserved(x, y){
  if (!pos_reserved[x])
    return false;
  
  if (!pos_reserved[x][y])
    return false;
  
  return true;
}

// reserve a position
function reservePosition(x, y, someInfo){
  // only reserve position if it's not already reserved
  if (!isReserved(x, y)){
    // check if you already have points with this x
    if (!pos_reserved[x]){
      // create one if needed
      pos_reserved[x] = {};
    }
  
    // save the point
    pos_reserved[x][y] = someInfo;
  }
  else{
    // dosomething...
  }
}
```

That's it... i think it's the best solution because your JSON object acts like a matrix... So you can easily access every points you saved earlier...

I added 'someValue' to show you that you can save information about this point. You can give a name or whatever you want... It's up to you, but you don't have to use it as weel ;)

Let me know if you have questions ;)

Romain

Comment: Ahah you're welcome ;) Don't hesitate to click the up arrow to say that the answer has been useful ;) Have a nice day !

Comment: I have :) It looks like it doesnt count 'cause i dont have enough reputation jet.

Comment: `pos_reserved.indexOf({"X": X,"Y": Y})` will never find an element, because you create a new element using `{"X": X,"Y": Y}` and this new element cannot exist in `pos_reserved`. And it is not a JSON object. JSON is only a textual representation of data used to exchange.

Comment: mhhhh you're right... I'm gonna remove this part of the answer. However I'm still convinced the way to go it the second solution ^^ Thanks for the remark ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the exact question, but I'll answer to the title.

[UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) is your best friend!

```
_.find(events, {DATE: "1970"})
//returns 1st object that matches the year: Object {TITLE: "event 1", DATE: "1970"}

_.filter(events, {DATE: "1970"}).length
//returns the number of objects with that year: 3
```